# Place Eclipse Project File in Separate Directory

Tags: android, eclipse, project, target

I'm using a default Eclipse project file generated for my Android application, and I want to keep it in a targets/ directory (along with other eclipse-specific files) in order to better organize my project structure (I also plan on adding a target for NetBeans).

Simple question, I suppose: Is this possible?

Comment: I mean, I have my project directory. Inside was the src/, bin/, lib/, etc. directories, as well as the .project and .classpath files. What I want to do, is move the .project and .classpath files (Eclipse-specific) to a new targets/eclipse/ directory.

Comment: I believe eclipse needs that .project file in the "root" of the project directory. that is how it knows it is a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this question, Ryan Conrad is correct in that Eclipse needs the .project files in the root of the project directory. As such it is not possible to move it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can define target or output destination by change the output folder. I guess you can do that by change the dir path under Property of the Android project.

If you want to reorganize all your Eclipse projects, you can create a new  workplace (Files/Switch workplace) and start creating new projects from now on.

Comment: Maybe I should revise my question.