# Eclipse new folder requires parent

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

Hi so I am relatively new to eclipse (java) but I am having a HUGE problem. I want to simply group my projects together into folder but I can't do that. Whenever I go to make a new folder, it REQUIRES me to enter a parent folder to put it in. The only folders it gives the option for me to select are the folders of past projects but that is the opposite of what I want. I want to put projects into folder, not put folders into projects. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put projects in different directories without making a new workspace.  This has been annoying me for a while, too.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news! See this question:

[Place Eclipse Project File in Separate Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058448/place-eclipse-project-file-in-separate-directory)